# Netbeans Git Can't add files to repository

Tags: php, git, netbeans

NetBeans IDE 7.1.2, Git User GUide (http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html) says I should see a tool tip over a file in the Projects Windows after I've Initialized a Git Repository.

I've never seen the top tip which says any files are added.

So next I tried a commit and and the commit dialog says no files.

So then I tried to create a branch and get "COMMIT [HEAD] does not exist"!

Desktop is Windows 7 and I'm new to Netbeans, Git and PHP and am probably just missing something very fundamental.

TIA,
George

Comment: How did you initialize the Git repository? In NetBeans or the command-line? I checked out a Git repo on the command-line, opened its NetBeans project, and it discovered the repo itself. Any file I create is automatically added to the repo and shows up in the commit dialog. I'm running 7.2beta, but it worked this way with 7.1 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can commit a file, you need to add it. The commandline command for that is:

```
> git add *
```

I suggest for the inital commit you do it on the commandline (as you're using windows, use the git-bash it's a great tool). After the add, Netbeans should be able to do the commit and from that on, Netbeans should be able to work as announced.

Just in case you feel more comfortable with git-bash, you can go back to there *anytime*. You can use Netbeans git integration with the git bash in parallel. Git takes care of that. So you get the best of two worlds (just google any git problem you run over and at least you should be able to solve it in git bash - if not within netbeans already).

Comment: Thanks hakre, that gave me enough to go on and with a bit of trail and error, am now happily using git in a local repository with NetBeans.